# Succeed in baby rocking game in Tomodachi?

Tags: tomodachi-life

I can't get the baby to stop crying. I started my game over to join my sister cause she got a new one. Because, she gave me her old one. The baby in my first game was easy to please. Now, she's just being difficult in the second one. Help?